# Splitting features of multi-part polygons according to condition(s) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, splitting, multipart, multi-polygon, split-by-attribute

I have a multi-part polygon with a large number of irregularly-shaped features (>600 features). I would like to split them into smaller sub-features/segments and assign a unique id to these smaller sub-features. Ideally, I would like to split these features based on the condition that the line/ border between them is straight.

However, some of the features hardly have straight lines running through them, so another way to split them could be based on a pre-determined area size.

Is there a function to do this automatically in QGIS? And, what are the steps to do this? I'm using QGIS version 3.4.4-Madeira.

For example, I would like to do something like this and then add a unique id row in the feature table:

[image: Example of feature that has been split into smaller segments]

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the ["Polygons to lines"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#polygons-to-lines) tool to convert the polygon borders into lines.
2. Use the ["Explode lines"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisexplodelines) tool to split the border lines into their separate segments.
3. Manually select and delete all the border lines *except* the middle border.
4. Use the ["Geometry by expression"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) tool to create a perpendicular line at the first vertex of every border line segment. Use an expression like this one, but substitute an appropriate distance value in *both* places where it says 500. The lines will be twice as long as the distance value.

   ```
   make_line(
       project(
           make_point($x_at(0), $y_at(0)), 500, angle_at_vertex($geometry, 0) + 90
           ),
       project(
           make_point($x_at(0), $y_at(0)), 500, angle_at_vertex($geometry, 0) - 90
           )
       )
   ```
5. Use the ["Split with lines"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#split-with-lines) to split the original polygon with the perpendicular lines

*Note:* This method will split the polygon at *every* vertex. In your example image, it looks like some of the segments are not perfectly straight. To avoid splitting the polygons at the vertices of the not-quite-straight segments, you'll need to do some processing between steps 3 and 4. Experiment with the ["Simplify"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgissimplifygeometries) and ["Snap geometries to layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#snap-geometries-to-layer) tools, or manually remove the extra vertices with the vertex tool.